# non-www along with https

Tags: htaccess, https, no-www

I need to set the following rules:

- redirect www to non-www (close www)
- redirect http to https (close http)

Suppose I have example.com , How to set the above rules together in htaccess?

Comment: See also http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem via :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the shorter version of your code :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```